# how to display Multiple values from angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and spring boot,i get all the record as a List from spring boot to angular 4 but in the angular form i get only single object data,how to list multiple values in Search box?

**component.ts**:
In this component  i am getting all the values but display single data!

characters=[];
      chars=[];

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.drugservice.getval().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.chars.data,
            this.characters = [
                {value: data[0].id},
                {label: data[0].name}
            ],
            alert(data[0].name)
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error Occured ');
        });
}
```

**ang.html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-4">            
   <ng-select [ngClass]="'ng-select'" [options]="characters"  formControlName="selectedCharacter"></ng-select>              
</div>
```

**Back end rerun Object Values:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ak"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "java"
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. You want to show all options in the `<select>`, or you only want to show the first result? Additionally, since your problem is frontend related, you don't need the [tag:spring-boot] tag (even though the data may come from a Spring boot application).

Comment: I want to show list of values in <ng-select > but its shows only one record! i want to show multiple records?....@g00glen00b

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do but the part of your code `data => {
            this.chars.data,
            this.characters = [
                {value: data[0].id},
                {label: data[0].name}
            ],
            alert(data[0].name)
        },` means nothing.

Comment: i am getting list of object stored  in the 'data' and  i going to store all the values to array[] of chars from the data,but  i am  getting  single object data??...@ Alexandre Annic

Comment: i want to show multiple values ??.....@ Alexandre Annic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, most of them within the `subscribe()` handler. First of all, the commas are making it very strange, but I guess that you're trying to do this:

```js
this.drugservice.getval().subscribe(data => {
  this.chars.data, this.characters = [{value:data[0].id},{label:data[0].name}];
  alert(data[0].name);
});
```

One issue with this code is that you only use `data[0]`, so if `data` contains multiple objects, you're only doing something with the first object. Probably, you want to do something like this:

```js
this.drugservice.getval().subscribe(data => {
  this.characters = data.map(obj => ({ value: obj.id, label: obj.name }));
});
```

Or a more reactive way to do this would be:

```js
this.drugservice
  .getval()
  .map(data => data.map(obj => ({ value: obj.id, label: obj.name })))
  .subscribe(data => this.characters = data);
```

By using the `map()` operator you can map all objects in the `data` array to the `{ value: ..., label: ... }` structure.

And last but not least, if you're using [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select), you should probably bind to `items` rather than to `options`:

```html
<ng-select [ngClass]="'ng-select'" [items]="characters" 
           formControlName="selectedCharacter">                             
</ng-select>
```

But according to the documentation of ng-select, you don't need to map your objects to a certain structure as long as you provide the correct `bindValue` property, so you might want to take a look into that.